# Issues with LSTM-based Time Series Prediction in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to predict time-series stock market data using TensorFlow and a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) with LSTM layers. However, I encountered an input data shape-related error. So, I need guidance on how to set up the input and output layers as well as the LSTM layers.

The data is historical stock market prices for the chosen stock (AAPL). It was retrieved using the Yahoo Finance API and then preprocessed. The mid prices and the exponential moving averages (EMA) were calculated. The data has been split into training and testing sets (80/20 split).

ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' custom_state1:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (200,), and the assigned value shape () are incompatible.

Here is the code which is not working:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
    
    # Define some placeholders and variables
    tf_learning_rate = tf.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32)
    tf_min_learning_rate = tf.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32)
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    
    # Simulate a custom LSTM cell
    class CustomLSTMCell(tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell):
        def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(units, **kwargs)
            self.custom_state1 = self.add_weight(
                shape=(units,),
                initializer='zeros',
                name='custom_state1'
            )
            self.custom_state2 = self.add_weight(
                shape=(units,),
                initializer='zeros',
                name='custom_state2'
            )
       
        def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
            h_tm1, c_tm1 = states
            inputs = inputs + h_tm1
    
            new_h, new_c = super().call(inputs, states, training=training)
            new_h += self.custom_state1
            new_c += self.custom_state2
    
            return new_h, [new_h, new_c]
    
    # Use the custom LSTM cell
    lstm_cell = CustomLSTMCell(units=200)
    
    # Simulate the loss calculation
    batch_size = 32  # Add the missing batch_size variable
    loss = 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean((tf.random.normal([batch_size, 1]) - tf.random.normal([batch_size, 1]))**2)
    
    # Simulate the optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(tf_learning_rate)
    gradients, v = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
    gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 5.0)
    optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, v))
    
    # Simulate the control_dependencies part
    with tf.control_dependencies([lstm_cell.custom_state1.assign(tf.zeros([200])), lstm_cell.custom_state2.assign(tf.zeros([200]))]):
        train_op = tf.no_op()
    
    # Initialize TensorFlow session
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    
        # Run the session
        for i in range(100):
            _, current_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={tf_learning_rate: 0.001})
            print(f"Step {i}, Loss: {current_loss}")
```

Comment: Please include the specific errors you encountered (i.e. the full [traceback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)). Also, in future, please keep questions concise: the longer it takes to interpret the problem and question the less likely you are to receive help.

Comment: thank appreciated!

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal working example to reproduce the error. Cuurently there is too much going on and it is very hard to pin down problematic parts. Also, you added the error in the edit message and not in the question itself.